# Setup the ONU (FIBER FIELD FF-E151A)

Tags: ethernet

I have this box in my grandma village, and also I have problems with setting it up. It works fine with one laptop, but when I plug it via ethernet in the other one, I see no Internet access. Also I cant connect to the Web-Interface ( 192.168.101.8 , 192.168.1.1 , 192.168.0.1 ). Please, help me to find any documentation or installation instructions, cause I can`t see it anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provider ties Internet access with MAC address. MAC-changer helped.

Answer (score 0):

In the immortal words of the IT crowd "Have you tried turning it off and on again?"

Our ONT (made by a different company) won't pick up a new router or other device connected to it until they are restarted.

It would probably be a better idea to add a router instead and have that connected to the ONU/ONT.

Comment: I have found the issue: in my provider`s information paper it is written that I should call them if I change the NIC or a computer. Maybe, they bind hardware information and subscriber`s account? Can I emulate grandma`s network chip on my laptop =) ?

Comment: Having it tied into a mac address would be odd. And potentially troublesome.

Comment: Yeah , they are going this way. Hello from wild Ukranian village!